# How to use awk or other tools to rearranged fields if matched

Tags: awk, field, match

I have a file from output of a lisp program:

```
(john (a b c (grade 90 good)))
(doe  (e f (grade 80 fair) g h i j))
(mary ((grade 100 best))
(jane (x y (grade 95 better) z))
```

I want to move (grade number description) to right next to the name; e.g.,

```
(john (grade 90 good) (a b c))
(doe  (grade 80 fair) (e f g h i j))
```

...

This is what I have, but it is ugly code and does not really give me the clean results I want as above; can someone please help? Thanks !!!

```
cat studentGrades | sed 's/[()]/ /g' | awk 
'{ if (/grade/)  
      {for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) 
           {if ($i=="grade") 
               {printf ("%s ( %s %s %s ) %s\n",$1, $i, $(i+1), $(i+2), $0)}}}  
   else {print $0} 
}'
```

Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use this:

```
awk -F'[()]' '{printf "(%s(%s)(%s%s))\n", $2, $4, $3, $5}' file
```

Output:

```
(john (grade 90 good)(a b c ))
(doe  (grade 80 fair)(e f  g h i j))
(mary (grade 100 best)())
(jane (grade 95 better)(x y  z))
```

The input field separator is set to either `(` or `)`. The rest is simply a case of rearranging the fields.

Comment: I give this `+1` since its easy to read and understand. The `sed` solution is not.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the brackets in 3rd line are not paired. I assume there was an ending `)` missing. I fixed it in my test. (see below)

this sed one-liner should do, it is gonna leave the 3rd line unchanged, since the description is empty.

```
sed 's/\(([^(]*\)\((.\+\)\((grade[^)]*)\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2\4/' file
```

If you want to "move" the empty description anyway, use this:

```
sed 's/\(([^(]*\)\((.*\)\((grade[^)]*)\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2\4/' file
```

**test** with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
(john (a b c (grade 90 good)))
(doe  (e f (grade 80 fair) g h i j))
(mary ((grade 100 best)))  <<<<<<<<- here I added a ")"
(jane (x y (grade 95 better) z))
```

with 1st one-liner:

```
kent$  sed 's/\(([^(]*\)\((.\+\)\((grade[^)]*)\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2\4/' f
(john (grade 90 good)(a b c ))
(doe  (grade 80 fair)(e f  g h i j))
(mary ((grade 100 best)))
(jane (grade 95 better)(x y  z))
```

with 2nd one-liner:

```
kent$  sed 's/\(([^(]*\)\((.*\)\((grade[^)]*)\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2\4/' f
(john (grade 90 good)(a b c ))
(doe  (grade 80 fair)(e f  g h i j))
(mary (grade 100 best)())
(jane (grade 95 better)(x y  z))
```